# How do I access knockout variables/observables in bootbox alert

Tags: knockout.js, bootbox

I would like to acces my knockout js viewmodel in a bootboxjs alert. Do you know why my code is not working?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bt2pffcd/1/

Simplified code is:

```
<div class="bootbox">
  <input data-bind="textinput: testText"/> Typed:
  <label data-bind="text: testText"></label>
</div>
<button data-bind=" click: bootBox">Launch bootbox!</button>
```

And my viewmodel and applybindings:

```
  var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.testText = ko.observable("Test");
    self.bootBox = function() {
      bootbox.alert($("div.bootbox").html());
    }

  }


  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle has errors. Look at the console

Comment: i looked it up however its not the trouble maker here im sure about that

Comment: I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt2pffcd/2/) with a different version of knockout and a reordered external resources - are you asking why the textbox in the bootbox alert isn't populated?

Answer (score 1):

I learned my viewmodel is not applied to bootbox elements because the bootbox dom elements are removed and added after applybindings is called. I openend my popup and called applybindings in console and voilla it worked. I would like to be able to use my viewmodel in bootbox.

So I came up with a solution. Bind initially to a specific div. And then create a div for bootbox content, after that create the bootbox popup call and put the content of the second div inside its message (with jquery.html) then apply binding to bootbox popup class[0] and victory is yours. Fiddle will be updated.

Comment: Try, if possible, to include the code from your jsFiddle in your answer, since even jsFiddle links are subject to link rot.